# scala function with various input data types

Tags: scala, apache-spark, functional-programming

Is there a way I can make a function in scala wherein I can enter various types of parameter inputs? Please refer to the sample code below. I want to make the code below into one function that would accept various data types for the input.

Example:

```
/** */
def toMatrix(A: Array[Double], m:Int, n:Int): Array[Array[Double]] = {
    var A_ = Array.apply(A.slice(0,n),A.slice(n*1,n*1+n))
    for (i <- 2 to (m-1)){
        A_ = A_ ++ Array(A.slice(n*i,(n*i)+n))
        }
    A_
}


/** */
def toMatrixInt(A: Array[Int], m:Int, n:Int): Array[Array[Int]] = {
    var A_ = Array.apply(A.slice(0,n),A.slice(n*1,n*1+n))
    for (i <- 2 to (m-1)){
        A_ = A_ ++ Array(A.slice(n*i,(n*i)+n))
        }
    A_
}

/** */
def toMatrixBoolean(A: Array[Boolean], m:Int, n:Int) = {
    var A_ = Array.apply(A.slice(0,n),A.slice(n*1,(n*1)+n))
    for (i <- 2 to (m-1)){
        A_ = A_ ++ Array(A.slice(n*i,(n*i)+n))
        }
    A_
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. And you also don't need mutable variable and ugly imperative loops :)
If you are using scala syntax, might as well take a moment or two to learn actually using the language :/

```
def toMatrix[T : ClassTag](a: Array[T], m:Int, n:Int) = a.grouped(n).toArray
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you are talking about type parametrization, or generics in Java world. You should go and read about it -- there are a lot of information in internet and books on the subject. Some examples from alvinalexander.com:

http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-classes-using-generic-types-examples

I personally recommend you the book Programming in Scala by Martin Odersky et al. It is slightly old now, but it is perfectly written and  thoroughly covers the language.